# slide up/down drop down menu

Tags: jquery, css

I want sub menus of main navigation to slide down on mouseover and slide up on mouseout.

Following is the page i am working on: http://jaspreetkaur.com/marg-moll/

Following is the jQuery code i have tried to create the effect, but the result is bit weird. I am not sure what i have done wrong in my code.

```
$('nav > ul > li').hover(
    function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
    },
    function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
    }
);
```

Comment: increase duration in `slideDown` and `slideUp`

Comment: what kind of weird. please give some description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that issue was related to my CSS code, i used position:absolute at a wrong place. It's working fine now.

Thank you all for your quick help :)

Answer (score 0):

i saw your site, The colors you have used are very nice. 
Anyways you can use .slideToggle("slow"); instead of .slideDown(200);
API [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) 
i hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think **weired**, you've mentioned in you question is about animation effect of your slideing.

You can use a little more duration in you `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`, as I commented you before.

For example.

```
$(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(1000);

$(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp(1000);
```

and so on what you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick mockup:

Html:

```
<li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Biographie</a>
<ul>                                   
     <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Einleitung</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Matisse</a></li>  
     <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Mein Portraitt</a></li>                                   
</ul> 
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Werke</a></li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("body li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {    

            $(this).mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
            });

            $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
            });

            $(this).find("ul").mousemove(function() {
                $(this).stop(true, true).show();
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

CSS

```
body ul{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    width: 40%;        
    background: #7ac0da;
    border-top: 5px solid #7ac0da;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity:0.8;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
body ul li a{
    line-height: 3.1em;
    color: white !important;
}

body ul li a:hover{    
    color: #D14836 !important;
}

body li{
float:left;
margin: 5px;
}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kHnpu/

Regards

​